# Validators showing up on input blur rather than submit

Tags: jquery, validation, jquery-validate

I am using this script on my form http://coder.cl/products/jquery-validators/#id_download and it does the validation well but it is validating on input blur rather than submit. I dont see it being bound to any blur or change events and the options.form_event is submit so I am not sure what is going on. Anyone have experience with this.

example validation initialization

```
 $('#form_first_name').addValidator({type: 'regex', regex : /^[a-z,-.' ]*[a-z][a-z,-.' ]*$/gi, allow_empty: false, language :'en', position: 'absolute', right: '-20px', top: '-10px' ,custom_message: 'Only letters, spaces, and, . are allowed'});
```

Answer (score 0):

Please read the overview .
jquery-validators is a jQuery plug-in with some predefined validators, but extensible to allow you to create field validations on change and focusout events. The plug-in runs individually for each field, without referring a specific form in the HTML.

Comment: yes I can see that but I have the form_event set to submit not to change or focusout. what is the syntax for disabling those features?

Comment: If you want to validate onsubmit. you can make your own validate function and call that on submit.If it returns true submit the form else return false.